# Not showing foreground in smooth transitions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, mask

I would like to achieve image blending with smooth transitions using alpha blending using and smoothed mask. I used Gaussian filter for the mask and now I'm trying to combine the other two images. I'm using the smoothed mask as a weight.

`x_i` and `y_i` .... color information for pixel i

`alpha_i` ... value of the mask in pixel i

formula: `z_i = alpha_i*x_i + (1 - alpha_i)*y_i`

My attempt:

```
mask = imread('mask.png');
foreground = imread('fg.jpg');
background = imread('bg.jpg');
[r,c,~]=size(mask);
A = zeros(size(foreground),'like', foreground);
fspe = fspecial('gaussian', 100);  
smoothMask = imfilter(double(mask), fspe, 'same'); 
for i=1:r 
  for j=1:c       
    for d=1:3            
      alpha = mask(i,j,d);
      A(i,j,d) = alpha*foreground(i,j,d)+(1-alpha)*background(i,j,d);           
    end    
  end
end
imshow(A);
```

In the end I get the background but the foreground is white. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` is of type `double` and in range `[0..255]`. When `imshow`ing images of type `double` the expected scale is `[0..1]` this is why all pixels are shown saturated.

Fix:

```
imshow(A,[])
```

Or

```
imshow(A/255)
```

---

A word about [vectorization](/questions/tagged/vectorization): In Matlab it is quite redundant to explicitly loop through all rows columns and channels just to multiply and sum images (3D arrays). It can be easily done

```
A = mask.*foreground + (1-mask).*background;
```

Isn't it lovely?

Note the difference between `*` operator and [`.*`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) operator - it's the difference between matrix multiplication and element-wise multiplication.

Comment: @den verify that your `mask`, `foreground` and `background` values are in the range of `[0..1]`. I believe that they are of type `uint8` in the range `[0..255]`. consider using [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html).

Comment: Ok I changed all the images to double and now I get the blended image but the result is the same as in my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905709/image-blending-with-mask) .I was expecting a better version not the same using this approach.

Comment: have you looked at your `fspe` filter? it is almost completely zero apart from its center. in order to "smooth" your mask, you need a wider filter. try `fspe=fspecial('gaussian', 21, sqrt(21) )` @den

Comment: @den glad I could help. please consider "accepting" my answer by clicking the "v" icon beside it.